# Controlar a ventoinha (fan) da CPU em C#

Tags: c#, wmi

Como faço para ler e definir a velocidade da ventoinha (fan) do CPU e também ler a velocidade atual?

Tentei utilizar este código mas também não consegui resultado.

```cs
[DllImport("Cimwin32.dll")]
static extern uint32 SetSpeed(in uint64 sp);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           SetSpeed(300);
}
```

Vi que existem duas classes que posso utilizar: o [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e o [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/), mas não encontrei nenhum exemplo de como faço para aplicar.

Alguém tem idéia de como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 9):

Esta DLL não possui esta chamada, portanto esta maneira irá falhar ao fazer a busca por este nome na biblioteca.

De acordo com [a documentação da Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393599(v=vs.85).aspx) este método não é implementado pelo WMI.

Caso este método estivesse implementado o código para chamá-lo, seria este:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementClass fanClass = new ManagementClass("CIM_Fan");

            ManagementBaseObject inParams = fanClass.GetMethodParameters("SetSpeed");
            inParams["DesiredSpeed"] = 1000;

            ManagementBaseObject outParams = fanClass.InvokeMethod("SetSpeed", inParams, null);

            Console.WriteLine("SetSpeed to 1000. returned: " + outParams["returnValue"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Porém o código falha na execução do método `InvokeMethod` porque o método não está implementado.

Lembrando que é necessário incluir uma referência assembly no projeto para `System.Management`.

Código baseado [neste exemplo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257364.aspx).

EDIÇÃO:

Parece que não é possível sem escrever um driver para o Windows, de acordo com [esta pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485448/programmatically-access-cpu-fan-on-a-laptop-windows).

Comment: Aconteceu o mesmo erro comigo. Conheces outra forma de tentar controlar o Fan por c#?

Comment: Editei a resposta, não parece ser possível sem escrever um driver =/